# Trying To Populate Drop Down Menus Using XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

What I am attempting to do is to use an XML file to load the next drop down menu items. It is so you are able to select your car's Make, Model, then year. This is to show customers on my website their vehicle's speaker sizes.
This is what I have right now, but I just cannot get it to work out.

```html
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
<head>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<title>demo of dropdown list using xml element data in JavaScript</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var course_data; // variable to hold data in once it is loaded
    $.get('http://creativenights.creativecaraudio.net/test/fitguide.xml', function(data) { // get the courses.xml file
        course_data = data; // save the data for future use
                            // so we don't have to call the file again
        var that = $('#courses'); // that = the courses select
        $('MAKE', course_data).each(function() { // find courses in data
            // dynamically create a new option element
            // make its text the value of the "title" attribute in the XML
            // and append it to the courses select
            $('<option>').text($(this).attr('MAKE')).appendTo(that);
        });
    }, 'xml'); // specify what format the request will return - XML

    $('#courses').change(function() { // bind a trigger to when the
                                      // courses select changes
        var val = $(this).val(); // hold the select's new value
        var that = $('#times').empty(); // empty the select of times
                                        // and hold a reference in 'that'
        $('MAKE', course_data).filter(function() { // get all courses...
            return val == $(this).attr('title'); // find the one chosen
        }).find('model').each(function() { // find all the times...
            // create a new option, set its text to the model, append to
            // the times select
            $('<option>').text($(this).text()).appendTo(that);  
        });
    });
});
</script>

<body>

Make:
<select id='courses'>
    <option value='0'>----------</option>
</select>
<br>
Model:
<select id='times'>
</head>


</body>
</html>
```

This is how my XML is laid out:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
<MAKE>ACURA</MAKE>
<Model>CL</Model>
<Year_From>2001</Year_From>
<Year_To>2003</Year_To>
<Front_Location_1>Door</Front_Location_1>
<Front_Size_1>6 1/2</Front_Size_1>
<Front_Location_2>Sail Panel</Front_Location_2>
<Front_Size_2>1    </Front_Size_2>
<Rear_Location_1>Deck</Rear_Location_1>
<Rear_Size_1>6 x 9</Rear_Size_1>
<Rear_Location_2></Rear_Location_2>
<Rear_Size_2></Rear_Size_2>
<Other_Speakers></Other_Speakers>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<MAKE>ACURA</MAKE>
<Model>CL</Model>
<Year_From>1999</Year_From>
<Year_To>1999</Year_To>
<Front_Location_1>Door</Front_Location_1>
<Front_Size_1>6 1/2</Front_Size_1>
<Front_Location_2>Sail Panel</Front_Location_2>
<Front_Size_2>1    </Front_Size_2>
<Rear_Location_1>Deck</Rear_Location_1>
<Rear_Size_1>6 x 9</Rear_Size_1>
<Rear_Location_2></Rear_Location_2>
<Rear_Size_2></Rear_Size_2>
<Other_Speakers></Other_Speakers>
</ROW>

<ROW>
<MAKE>ACURA</MAKE>
<Model>CL</Model>
<Year_From>1997</Year_From>
<Year_To>1998</Year_To>
<Front_Location_1>Door</Front_Location_1>
<Front_Size_1>6 1/2</Front_Size_1>
<Front_Location_2>Sail Panel</Front_Location_2>
<Front_Size_2>1    </Front_Size_2>
<Rear_Location_1>Deck</Rear_Location_1>
<Rear_Size_1>6 x 9</Rear_Size_1>
<Rear_Location_2></Rear_Location_2>
<Rear_Size_2></Rear_Size_2>
<Other_Speakers></Other_Speakers>
</ROW>
```

What I'm trying to make is like what's on the bottom of the [metraonline.com](http://metraonline.com/) website

I have a live demo of what I have made so far here:
http://creativenights.creativecaraudio.net/test/dropdown/xmltest_1.html
Any help would be appreciated, I've tried to get this for a couple weeks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You don't have possibility to query DB after each select then You can leverage jQuery [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Basic example would be:

```
// Will hold our XML DOM
var $xml;

// Select elements
var make = $('#make');
var model = $('#model');
var year = $('#year');

$.get('http://46.101.139.188/fitguide.xml', function(data){
  $xml = $(data);
  var rows = $(data).find('ROWSET ROW');
  var makes = [];

  $.each(rows, function(index, element){
    var _make = $(element).find('MAKE').text();
    makes.push('<option value="' + _make + '">' + _make + '</option>');
  });

  makes = $.unique(makes);
  make.append(makes.join('\n'));

}, 'xml');

$('#make').on('change', function(){
  var _value = $(this).val();
  var _models = $xml.find('ROWSET ROW:contains("'+_value+'")');
  var models = [];

  $.each(_models, function(index, element){

    var _model = $(element).find('Model').text();
    models.push('<option value="' + _model + '">' + _model + '</option>');
  });
  models = $.unique(models);
  model.append(models.join('\n'));

});
```

Demo in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Alczt2rtrjoR7boXSfO7?p=preview)

Comment: Yes! Now I am getting somewhere, now if only when i change the "MAKE" of the vehicle to another after i select it, it keeps the old make's vehicles loaded in the second drop down. And I know for the years to work properly I need to update my XML file, but once I select a vehicle, how can I determine what results show?

I have actually determined it does in fact add the new selections models into the dropdown, but it doesn't remove the old ones.

Comment: @Matt, You can clear `select` before appending `model.append(models.join('\n'));` before this line add `model.find('option').remove();`

Comment: Okay, I now have it to where I am able to get the year, make, and model, now that I have this information, how can I return the results from the user's selection?
My working copy is located here:
http://creativenights.creativecaraudio.net/test/dropdown/fitguide3.xml